# Create Circular Button in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, button

Can any one tell me how to create the rounded button (Circular Button) in iPhone by using interface builder?

Comment: you can create a customButton with a Circular image as its background,
choose button type as CustomType

Comment: you can find the Button Type property in Attribute Inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a circular button than create an image with a circular shape filled with whatever you want to be displayed in the circle. Make sure your image has an alpha channel and delete all the area around your circle so the background of your image is transparent (alpha =0). ([gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) is free and easy to use application for such images)

In IB create a round rect button with type custom button. Select your image as the background of your button and there you have it.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> 

CALayer * l = [control layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:5.0];
    [l setBorderWidth:2.0];
```

Adjust cornerRadius according to your need..

Comment: UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ABC.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_Click) orControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.frame = CGRectMake(135.0, 180.0, 40.0, 40.0);
button.clipsToBounds = YES;
button.layer.cornerRadius = 20;//half of the width
button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
button.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
[self.view addSubview:button];

Above code is working fine but not for button taken in IB.